# What ways are there to increase one's spellcasting attribute for spellcasting purposes?

Tags: optimization, anima-beyond-fantasy, attributes, spellcasting

I was recently looking at the Regeneration spell (Creation 10), and wondering how I could achieve Regeneration 20 with it.  This would seem to require a spellcasting attribute score greater than 20, which is as far as I know, not something you can point-buy up to.

Assuming that all of core (including Game Master's Toolkit), the Prometheum; Dominus; and Arcana Exxets, and additionally Gaia: Beyond The Dreams are available how *else* can one raise one's spellcasting stat?  Answers may assume that any attribute that can be a spellcasting attribute, is a spellcasting attribute.

We are using the variant rules where one can spend level-up points on advantages.

To be clear - the question I am asking is "how can I boost my spellcasting attribute higher than 20", and not "how can I get Regeneration 20".

Comment: Of note: Game Master's Toolkit does have an advantage that allows you to determine spellcasting potential according to POW instead of INT...

Comment: New Magic system on Core Exxet caps regeneration at 16.

Comment: We're not using Core Exxet (mostly - we have adopted some of it), @Random, but yeah, this is a theoretical exercise anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve regeneration 20 by any normal means in a campaign (Including magic). It is not intended either. To quote the book:

> *Regeneration 19 requires a Gnosis of 40; Regeneration 20 requires a Gnosis of 45

You can find this at the bottom of page 53 of the core book.

Stats are hard capped at 20, as it would no longer make sense beyond that. What would Strength 21 even do for example?

That said, there are many ways to increase your spell casting attribute. Here is a fairly exhaustive list.

- Artifacts - There are a wide range of effects that could satisfy this.
- Creature Powers (Multiple places, Creature book and back of the core book)
- Even Level ups (Base Book)
- Nodes of Power (Arcana Exxet pg 122)
- Sanctum Sanctorum's (Arcana Exxet pg 124)
- Rituals (Base Book)
- Shamanism - Helpful Spirits (Arcana Exxet pg15)
- Spell Specialist Metamagic (Arcana Exxet pg28)
- Racial Bonuses (Multiple places, Creature book and back of core book)
- Pacts with a Dragon could cause you to gain in a spell casting stat
- Familiaring a demon (Creature book)
- Transformation: The Seals of the Dragon (Dominus Exxet pg 93)
- Various legacies of blood (Dominus Exxet pg 74 onward)

There are probably more.

Comment: Yes, the nature of regeneration 20 would preclude getting it in normal circumstances, but that's context, not content.  Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: (also, with the perfect storm of luck and vaguely exploit-shaped stuff, it'd be *possible* to bootstrap up to 45 Gnosis.  You'd just have to pull off casting Chimera on yourself and then also finding someone to either Imitate Spell or Steal Spell or what have you both Light Ascension *and* Dark Ascension.  So it would require a perfect storm of events, but it wouldn't be *impossible.*)

Comment: I was pretty specific in saying it wasnt impossible. Just extremely improbable, and basically depends entirely on what the GM is OK with.